# Using Chosen (jQuery plugin) for an <input type="text" />

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I know the title is slightly confusing, but what I want is pretty simple. [Here is the example link.](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/)

I simply want to use the dropdown list that appears for Multiple Selects for a simple input. Is this possible?

If not, maybe something similar to chosen?

Comment: So what is the issue? Don't they provide sample code?

Comment: have you considered jquery autocomplete?

Comment: Where would the options come from if it's a text field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try **select2** which is based off of chosen but more functionality.

here is the demo page: http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/